# case class overloading in Scala

Tags: scala, constructor-overloading

I have a legacy message in my system, and I would like to be able to map it new version the message in my system.

Why can't I overload my case class?

```
case class Message(a:Int, b:Int)
case class NewMessage(a:Int, b:Int, c:Int) {
  def this(msg : Message) = this(a = msg.a, b = msg.b, c = 0)
}
val msg = Message(1,2)
val converted = NewMessage(msg)
```

This code doesn't seem to compile. :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must explicitly call constructor by using `new` operator:

```
val converted = new NewMessage(msg)
```

It works because you are actually defining a second constructor in `NewMessage` while ordinary:

```
NewMessage(1, 2, 3)
```

is translated to:

```
NewMessage.apply(1, 2, 3)
```

Comment: @Terenced: well... yes. I just checked it with Scala 2.9.1 and the code compiles by adding `new` operator just fine

Comment: Please state that you added the `new`. I tried for minutes to spot the difference to the op.

Comment: @ziggystar: added, thanks. Note that you are allowed (and encouraged) to modify any post on SO.

Answer (score 11):

You're overloading the constructor, while what you want to do is overload the apply method. You can do this on the companion object:

```
case class NewMessage(a: Int, b: Int, c: Int) 

object NewMessage {
  def apply(msg: Message) = new NewMessage(a = msg.a, b = msg.b, c = 0)
}

val converted = NewMessage(msg)
```